# Magento - customers to have a image and video gallery attached to their profile

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, image-upload, gallery, multiple-file-upload

As part of my website i need customers to have a media gallery a part of their account where they can upload multiple photos to their account. I have tried to search for extensions and help on this topic but I cannot find anything all I can find is allowing customers to upload product images which I do not want. could anyone give me some advice on this or an extension that does what I need it to do? (It would need to be an extension on the customer account that allows multiple photos to be added)

Comment: yes i have created same functionality in my website

Comment: how did you do it? because im not sure where to start and whats the best way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think all the functionality that you want exists in Magento but you can start with something that covers part of your requirements then develop the rest on your own.

Something like this allows you to add a picture to a customer profile

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/upload-profile-image.html

You can then extend that to allow for multiple pictures on a profile.